# want to understand synthetic division & polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Can someone define Synthetic division and whats its formula or method to solve a polynomial, for example:

> **1)** Use synthetic division to find the value of $k$ if $-2$ is a zero of polynomial:   $$x^{3} + 4x^{2} + kx + 8$$
>
> **2)** Use synthetic division to find the value of $p$ and $q$ if $x+1$ and $x-2$ are the factors of $$x^{3}+ px^{2} + qx + 6$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanically it is the same thing as polynomial long division.  Unfortunately it is difficult to do the formatting here.

$x^3 + 4x^2 + kx + 8\\
(x+2)(x^2) - 2x^2 + 4x^2 + kx + 8\\
(x+2)(x^2)  + 2x^2 + kx + 8\\
(x+2)(x^2 + 2x) - 4x  + kx + 8\\
(x+2)(x^2 + 2x - 4+k) +8-2k + 8\\
(x+2)(x^2 + 2x - 4+k) -2k+16 \\
$

In a clumsy way I have divided the polynomial by $(x+2)$

If $-2$ is a root of the polynomial.

$(-2)^3 + 4(-2)^2 + k(-2) + 8 = 0$

But since we did that polynomial division.  We don't need to plug $-2$ into every $x$ term to see that we can $0$ out a large block of the polynomial.

$(-2+2)(x^2 + 2x - 4+k) -2k+16  = 0$

$-2k+16  = 0\\k = 8$

Comment: Thank you Doug, I have done the synthetic division and then applied the last part of your answer and found the value of k = 8.. and i have already solved the part 2 of question..